# Encountered "EOFError: EOF when reading a line" on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, finance, pythonanywhere

I was trying to run a script in PythonAnywhere (this is my first time using it), but it said my code had an EOF error. When I run it in flask_app.py, it works, but when I refresh the website and try it on the site itself, it gives me this error.

```html
Error running WSGI application
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
File "/var/www/samtheconqueror_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
from flask_app import app as application  # noqa
File "/home/SamtheConqueror/mysite/flask_app.py", line 11, in <module>
IVI = float(input("Enter the initial value of investment: "))
```

Is this because I am using flask?

I am trying to calculate the return on investment in the script.
Here is the code:

```html
Num = 0
IVI = 0
FVI = 0
Dvi = 0
Com = 0
age = 0

loop1 = True
while loop1:
    try:
        IVI = float(input("Enter the initial value of investment: "))
        loop1 = False
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid.")
print("")
loop2 = True
while loop2:
    try:
        FVI = float(input("Enter the final value of investment: "))
        loop2 = False
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid.")
print("")
loop3 = True
while loop3:
    try:
        Num = int(input("Enter the number of shares purchased: "))
        loop3 = False
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid.")
print("")
Cost = IVI * Num
loop4 = True
while loop4:
    try:
        Dvi = float(input("Enter amount earned from dividends: "))
        loop4 = False
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid.")
print("")
loop5 = True
while loop5:
    try:
        Com = float(input("Enter the amount spent on commissions: "))
        loop5 = False
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid.")

ROI1 = (FVI - IVI) * Num + Dvi - Com
ROI2 = ROI1 / (IVI * Num)
ROI3 = ROI2 * 100
print(ROI3)
print_value = str(ROI3)
print("")
print("ROI = " + print_value + "%")
print("")

t_f = input("Calculate Annualized ROI(t/f)?")
loop6 = True
while loop6:
    if t_f == "t":
        loop6 = False
        pass
    elif t_f == "f":
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid")
print("")
loop7 = True
while loop7:
    try:
        age = float(input("Enter number of years you have held this investment for: "))
        loop7 = False
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid.")
print("")

years = 1 / age
aROI = (1 + ROI2)
aROI0 = pow(aROI, years)
aROI1 = (aROI0 - 1) * 100
print_value2 = str(aROI1)
print("Annualized ROI = " + print_value2 + "%")
```

Comment: Seems like pythonAnywhere scripts aren't able to use `input()`.

Comment: `input` waits for input from the terminal, which is not available in a web app. See [https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/169/](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/169/)